# Meteor: JS alertbox 'cancel' is deleting my db entry instead of canceling the requested delete

Tags: javascript, meteor, alert

I have an alert box on a delete option, but when 'cancel' is pressed it still deletes the data :(

Here's the button in my html page.

```
<input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove Player" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
```

Here's the delete code in the js file:

```
'click .remove': function(){
    var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
    PlayersList.remove(selectedPlayer);
}
```

What does the alert box return on false that I can use in an if statement around my remove function? - What's the variable name of the alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you have it set up you have two click event handlers, but the button onclick won't prevent the template event from being triggered.

Try removing the `onclick` event from the button and move it into the template event:

```
'click .remove': function(){
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
        PlayersList.remove(selectedPlayer);
    }
}
```